# Solving an equation for B

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having an issue solving this. I wrote this equation to find the with of a bar for a bar chart that is comparative.
\begin{equation}
D-P*(N+1) = ((N-1)*M)*B*0.75+N*B
\end{equation}

Comment: D and P are numbers, integers. D is the size of the drawable area, P is the padding between bars.

Comment: some one else edited it... should be fixed

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah, my bad sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No guarantee that the result will be an integer, but just distribute the $B$ out of the terms on the right and divide.

$\begin{equation}
D-P*(N+1) = ((N-1)*M)*B*0.75+N*B
\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}
D-P*(N+1) =( ((N-1)*M)*0.75+N)*B
\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}
(D-P*(N+1))/( ((N-1)*M)*0.75+N)=B
\end{equation}$

Comment: Thanks, Looks good. Forgot about taking B out of the terms on the right.

Comment: Is "*" a common operator for multiplication? I thought it was "\times" or "\cdot"?

Comment: @Gigili:  Some people use it.  It is easier in handwriting to distinguish from the variable $x$.  Many programming languages use it.  I followed the OP which let me copy/paste.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Ah OK, good to know. Thanks. Actually I was aware of the programming usage of it but I recalled someone recommended to avoid using it in LaTeX.

Comment: My first math question on math.stackexchange... I am a programmer so I always use stackOverflow. In programming * is a common for multiplication. Here is the equation in objective-c:            float barWidth = (drawableArea-SECTION_SPACING*([barArray count]+1)) / ((([barArray count]-1)*[barSetArray count])*0.75+[barArray count]);